# What is the difference between transaldolase and transketolase in the pentose phosphate pathway?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

What is the difference between transaldolase and transketolase in the pentose phosphate pathway? From what I understand, they both catalyze the transfer of carbon chains from 1 aldose into 1 ketose to produce 1 aldose and a ketose, though transketolase transfers 2 carbons while transaldolase transfers 3 carbons. Is that the only difference? If so, then why they were named "aldolase" and "ketolase"?

Answer (score 1):

An aldol is a $\beta$-hydroxy ketone or aldehyde, and is the product of an aldol addition.

[image]
The enzyme that cleaves the bond formed (red) is known as an aldolase. The transaldolase reaction begins by aldol cleavage that is, cleavage of the bond in red.

[image]

Transketolase on the other hand simply cleaves off the ketone group from the substrate. It does not perform an aldol cleavage.
[image]

Apart form this, the mechanisms of action of the two enzymes vary considerably. For instance transketolase requires thiamine pyrophosphate (TPP) as a cofactor but transaldolase does not.